# Payara server 5 asadmin command fails to read user input

Tags: server, payara

There seems to be a problem with the payara 5 asadmin command. When you launch the command from Windows 7 cmd and the program prompts for user input and you start typing it throws an exception.

Version 4.1 works just fine.

```
asadmin> list-domains
CLI141: No Domains to list.
Command list-domains executed successfully.
asadmin> create-domain ioit
Enter admin user name [Enter to accept default "admin" / no password]>
Enter the admin password [Enter to accept default of no password]> 
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOError: java.io.IOException
: The parameter is incorrect
    at java.io.Console.readPassword(Console.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.readPassword(CLICommand.java:1191)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getPassword(CLICommand.java:1134)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.CreateDomainCommand.getAdminPassword(CreateDomainCommand.java:369)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.servermgmt.cli.CreateDomainCommand.validate(CreateDomainCommand.java:236)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Payara 5.184, which has been fixed by [this PR](https://github.com/payara/Payara/pull/3528) which will be included in the next release of Payara (5.191).